# Angular - How can I clear factory variables when the view changes?

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I'm fairly new to angular, so bear with me. :-)
I have a list of contacts in one view. I put together a service with some setter and getter functions to hold the contact ID. When the user clicks a contact on the list view, it sets the ID in the service and moves to the edit form view. This is working well, but when I'm done editing and click to go back to the list view I want to clear the variables in the service. How would I do that?
I found one other answer on this topic, but I think it's using the built in angular router instead of ui-router.

[Angular updating and clearing factory variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341037/angular-updating-and-clearing-factory-variables)

Also, wouldn't the method in that answer also clear the variables when the user moved from the list to the edit form in the first place?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to persist that information in a service? I'd keep the collection in the service and tell the view which item to look for using the route params.

Comment: As I said, I am new to angular. From what I had gathered, in order to pass info from one controller to another, I needed to use a service. Let me reiterate: I am new. :-D If you can give me more details on a better way, I am all ears-- er...eyes. Thanks!

Comment: The angularjs tutorial has a great example https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial. That said, angularjs has a gaping hole where the business logic layer should be. I think most advanced developers wind up creating one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a route change you can use $locationChangeStart, see [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

For example in your edit controller, register for the event on route change:

```
var onloc = $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, newUrl, oldUrl) {                
    myService.cleanUp(whatever);
    onloc();           
});
```

Comment: Is "=>" valid js syntax? My editor is choking on it.

Comment: Had to change to: `$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, newUrl, oldUrl)` but it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah sorry about that - I use TypeScript, just typed it out on the fly, glad it solved. I've removed the sugar in the code sample.

Comment: Ah, excellent. Thanks! I haven't gotten into all the coding helpers for js. I use sass for css, but that's about it. :-)