# Clear data on logout with injected controllers (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parent-child, controllers

I have a parent controller with two injected child controllers as follows:

```
.controller('parentCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$controller', '$uibModal', 
     function ($scope, $http, $controller, $uibModal) {

    $controller('firstChildCtrl', { $scope: $scope })
    $controller('secondChildCtrl', { $scope: $scope })

}])
```

When the user logs out, the login controller emits a logout event:

```
$scope.$emit('logout');
```

All my other controllers clear their data on receiving this event, as follows:

```
 $scope.initial = [];

    $rootScope.$on("logout", function (event) {
        $scope.activities = angular.copy($scope.initial);
    });
```

So my question is, how can I get the parent controller to clear the data in its child scopes (because it isn't doing that)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest using a service (or services) for this information rather than passing it through scopes. Then on logout, rather than emitting an event you can clear the data from the service(s) directly

Comment: Thanks - I have some services for fetching the data from the server. I am not sure how to clear the data from them. I guess it would make sense to inject the services into the controller instead of the controllers.

Comment: I have now rewritten my controller to use all the services instead of injecting controllers. Now I just need to figure out how to clear the data from the service. If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I will happily mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Aha!  **Angular updating and clearing factory variables** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341037/angular-updating-and-clearing-factory-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end was have a controller where the factories (services to fetch data) were external to the controller, and I injected multiple services into my controller.

```
.controller('multiCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$uibModal', '$q', 'getApples', 'getPears', 
        function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $uibModal, $q, getApples, getPears) {

var myApples = getMyApples.fetch(function (apples) {
      $scope.apples = apples;

      var theApples = $scope.apples;

      });

var myPears = getMyPears.fetch(function (pears) {
      $scope.pears = pears;

      var thePears = $scope.pears;

      });
});
```